# Printing Ask Ubuntu pages

Tags: support, font

I read [How do I recover my data from an encrypted home directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38336/how-do-i-recover-my-data-from-an-encrypted-home-directory) and upon printing hardcopy of this, the font size is under 10 points. That is way too small to read easily. When I tried copy & paste into a word processor, that failed, too.

What is the purpose of Stack Exchange sites printing in type too small to read or in Stack Exchange sites not allowing the font size to be controlled by the person doing the printing? Is it possible to add a Print feature to these sites?

The image is at 100%.[image: Harcopy of the printed page]

Comment: You can zoom in on your page.

Comment: No, the Print "Scale" function is grayed out. IMO, this should not be a function of the printer. That is, if I had a HP Printer, "Scale" would work, but not with a Canon Printer. If you mean CTRL+ to enlarge the screen, that doesn't cause printing to be larger. Or when it does (other webpages), text is not printed, or some scrolls right off the screen and paper.

Comment: You can set the default font size in your browser, right?

Comment: You are confusing "screen font" with "printer font". Thanks.

Comment: @MarkPreston well, if you increase the screen font and make a PDF of the page, the PDF should use the larger font size, IIRC. Then print the PDF.

Comment: I did as you said. And in the Print menu, I scaled the size to 125% larger. Still the print is the same size as the original. Thanx.

Answer (score 3):

You may prefer the view shown by [StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/), which is an unofficial, community-maintained site that obtains and hosts copies of posts from Stack Exchange sites (with proper attribution) though Stack Exchange's published API, as needed, and displays them in a way intended to be better suited for printing.

**Here's [your question](http://www.stackprinter.com/export?question=38336&service=askubuntu).**

Some more information on StackPrinter is available on the website and also [this StackApps post](https://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite). To quote:

> **StackPrinter** is a website that pulls the main details of a given question, all its answers, comments and votes  formatting them in a
>   simple essential printable view.
>
> I've created this micro web application basically to add a
>   *"Printer-Friendly"* feature to the Stack Exchange Network sites, trying to remove some `@Media Print CSS` limitations like hidden
>   comments, pagination and empty spaces. (rationale [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/36709/printer-friendly-button/36743#36743))

See also [that meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36709/printer-friendly-button/36743#36743) and [this other one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19356/printer-friendly-layout-truncates-long-titles-on-firefox/50871#50871).

Comment: The link you provided, did not print a page with reasonable size font. readable. In fact, it is the exact same size as what I provided as an example. My modern Canon Maxify MB series printer Linux drivers show no way to "Scale" the page printed "up" so as to make it readable. SCALE is grayed out.

Answer (score 2):

Printing a web page is more related to your choice of browser to Ask Ubuntu itself. **:-)**

E.G. I'm currently using FireFox and that has an "Enter Reader View" mode in the address bar like this:

[image: Screenshot of OP question]

(The little page icon just before the <sup>**...**</sup> at the rightmost of the address bar itself)

Pressing that first and then printing prints perfectly at 150 on my printer.